# Mixing menuItem.setIntent with onOptionsItemSelected doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, menuitem

While extending a sample Android activity that fires some other activities from its menu, I came to have some menu items handled within `onOptionsItemSelected`, and some menu items (that just fired intents) handled by calling `setIntent` within `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Basically something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(0, MENU_ID_1, Menu.NONE, R.string.menu_text_1);
    menu.add(0, MENU_ID_2, Menu.NONE, R.string.menu_text_2);

    menu.add(0, MENU_ID_3, Menu.NONE, R.string.menu_text_3).
        setIntent(new Intent(this, MyActivity_3.class));

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case (MENU_ID_1):
            // Process menu command 1 ...
            return true;

        case (MENU_ID_2):
            // Process menu command 2 ...
            // E.g. also fire Intent for MyActivity_2 
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Apparently, in this situation the Intent set on MENU_ID_3 is never fired, or anyway the related activity is never started.

Android javadoc at some point goes like <<[if you set an intent on a menu item] **and nothing else handles the item**, then the default behavior will be to [start the activity with the intent]>>.

What does it actually mean "and nothing else handles the item"?
Is it enough to return false from `onOptionsItemSelected`?
I also tried not to call `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` at the beginning and only invoke it in the default switch case, but I had same results.

Does anyone have any suggestion? 
Does Android allow to mix the two type of handling?

Thanks for your time everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The solution was dumb enough. The destination activity name (say `MyActivity_3` in the example) was mispelled in the manifest.

I changed the 3rd menu item handling to the classic switch logic in `onOptionsItemSelected` and I got an `ActivityNotFoundException` exception in Eclipse debugger.

By handling the menu item in the "setIntent way", no exception was thrown. Although if I looked at the LogCat, I could have spotted a MenuItemImpl: `Can't find activity to handle intent; ignoring`.